# Postgresql удаление строки по ключу с неизвестным к нему путем в json поле

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица, в jsonb столбце `obj_structure` которой у каких то строк есть вот такие данные

```
{
"0": {"type": "string", "caption": "Страна", "DefaultValue": "РФ"}, 
"1": {"type": "string", "caption": "Город", "DefaultValue": "Москва"}, 
"6": {"type": "groupmembers", "checked_groups": ["c9a9d6a7-91a2-2584-61f0-1264a3be95ef", "bb3ec863-b34c-dc54-31fb-30432e2a6b40"]}
}
```

Подскажите, как мне найти и удалить строки, у которых в значение ключа `checked_groups` входит `c9a9d6a7-91a2-2584-61f0-1264a3be95ef`? Как сделать это, зная полный путь, я прекрасно представляю

```
DELETE FROM "_object_tpls" WHERE obj_structure->'6' @> '{"checked_groups": ["bb3ec863-b34c-dc54-31fb-30432e2a6b40"]}'
```

но проблема в том что ключ "6" заранее неизвестен, тут может быть и 17, и 120  и мне надо как то удалить строки, значение данного ключа у которых заранее неизвестно

спасибо!